# Como atribuir uma variavel java para document.getElementBy Id

Tags: javascript, id

Tenho o seguinte código abaixo, onde desejo armazenar o valor da variável contida em `document.getElementById`, que vem do input, e que deveria ser "text".
Esta linha de programação apenas imprime na tela o valor do input inicial, mas não armazena. Tentei associar ao var nota, e dei um comando de imprimir para ver se realmente ficou registrado, deveria aparecer escrito o valor do input duas vezes, mas só aparece uma vez. Desejo usar estava variável nova, para outro fim. O que estaria errado?

```
<input id="text">
......
........
<script>
  var speaker = new RobotSpeaker();
  function talk() {
    speaker.speak("pt", document.getElementById("text").value);///esta linha imprime o texto FALADO, na tela
    var nota = document.getElementById("text").value); //salvaria em nota o valor de text??
    console.log(nota.value); // Recuperando o valor:
    window.document.write("nota");///imprime na tela de novo???
  }
```

Comment: Cadê a variável Java mencionada no título?

Answer (score 0):

Não sei qual é o erro que estas a ter, mas tenta assim:

```
function talk() {
   speaker.speak("pt", document.getElementById("text").value); // ve se o problema não é esta linha, comenta-a para confirmar.
   var nota = document.getElementById("text").value;
   console.log(nota);
   window.document.write(nota);
}
```

Atenção que o console.log apenas mostra o valor da variável na consola do browser, o document.write é que imprime na página.

Comment: O que mudou no código?

Comment: Acho que sua segunda linha vai dar erro

Comment: var nota = document.getElementById("text").value) tinha um ")" a mais, nas linha do console.log, como a nota já era o value, fazer nota.value vai dar erro. Na ultima fazer write("nota") vai escrever nota em vez do valor.

Comment: @ArturoTemplário a apagar os comentarios tinha deixado la um pouco que estava na outra linha

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi direito o objetivo da sua pergunta, e me parece que você não tem bem firmados os conceitos de atribuição e uso de variáveis. Seu código também tem alguns erros:

```
var nota = document.getElementById("text").value);
```

Aqui, o parentese de fechamento final está sobrando, e provavelmente vai causar erros cedo ou tarde. É necessário remove-lo:

```
var nota = document.getElementById("text").value;
```

Aqui, o valor do input com o id "text" já ficou armazenado na variável `nota`

```
console.log(nota.value);
```

O valor de nota é uma string, portanto você não precisa colocar `nota.value`. Apenas assim já é suficiente:

```
console.log(nota);
```

Aqui é a parte que não entendi o que você pretende:

```
window.document.write("nota");
```

Se você queria escrever a variável nota na sua tela, basta tirar as aspas.

```
window.document.write(nota);
```

Se você colocar as aspas, será interpretado como uma string com o valor "nota", e vai escrever literalmente isso na tela.

Comment: Ok grato, estarei fazendo as alterações e informando.